# prosemirror: converting JSON output into HTML

Tags: prose-mirror

I'm trying to convert ProseMirror's JSON output back to HTML (to save it from one db to another). I am new with ProseMirror and I'm not sure I fully understand the relation between model, state and schema.

Judging from what I have read https://github.com/ProseMirror/prosemirror/issues/455 and https://discuss.prosemirror.net/t/example-of-converting-between-formats-for-the-purpose-of-saving/424,

I should first create a new state based on a basic schema, then use the DOMSerializer and attach the output to a temporary element (then get innerHtml). 
Does that sound about right? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 13):

After some digging, here's how I got this to work:

1. Create a node using .fromJSON
2. Make a DOMSerializer based on the schema used by the editor
3. Pass the node to the serializer

My code is below.

```js
const { schema } = require("prosemirror-schema-basic")
const { Node, DOMSerializer } = require("prosemirror-model")
const jsdom = require("jsdom").JSDOM

let dom = new jsdom('<!DOCTYPE html><div id="content"></div>')
let doc = dom.window.document
let target = doc.querySelector("div")
//Demo JSON output from ProseMirror
let content = {
  "doc": {
    "type": "doc",
    "content": [{
      "type": "paragraph",
      "attrs": {
        "align": "left"
      },
      "content": [{
        "type": "text",
        "text": "My sample text"
      }]
    }]
  },
  "selection": {
    "type": "text",
    "anchor": 16,
    "head": 16
  }
}

let contentNode = Node.fromJSON(schema, content.doc)

DOMSerializer
  .fromSchema(schema)
  .serializeFragment(contentNode.content, {
    "document": doc
  }, target)

console.log(doc.getElementById("content").innerHTML)
//<p>My sample text</p>
```

Comment: kind of a pain for something that should probably be built in

Comment: might be able to use `<OnChangeHTML onChange={onChangeHtml}/>` if you want to do it when your editor content updates. See [docs](https://remirror.io/docs/api/react-core#variable-onchangehtml) and [getting started](https://remirror.io/docs/5-min-tutorial/#get-the-current-state)

Answer (score 0):

Note for future readers. If you're using React and you want to get the markdown when the editor's contents update, then here is an example.

```js
import { OnChangeJSON, Remirror } from '@remirror/react';
import { MarkdownExtension } from 'remirror/extensions';
import { useRemirror } from '@remirror/react';
import { RemirrorJSON } from '@remirror/core';


export interface MarkdownControlledEditorProps {
export interface MarkdownControlledEditorProps {
  onChangeJson: (json: RemirrorJSON) => void,
  onChangeMarkdown: (markdown: string) => void,
  initialContent?: string,
}
export const MarkdownControlledEditor = ({
  onChangeJson,
  onChangeMarkdown,
  initialContent,
}: any) => {
  const { manager } = useRemirror({
    selection: 'start',
    extensions: RemirrorExtensionsPreset,
  });

  const _onChangeJson = (json: RemirrorJSON) => {
    onChangeContent({
      json,
      html: manager.store.helpers.getHTML(),
      text: manager.store.helpers.getText(),
      markdown: manager.store.helpers.getMarkdown(),
    });
  }

  return (
    <Remirror
      autoFocus={true}
      autoRender={'start'}
      manager={manager}
      initialContent={initialContent}
    >
      <OnChangeJSON onChange={_onChangeJson}/>
    </Remirror>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

### Here is how to convert prose mirror JSON into HTML in NodeJS

Solution using [happy-dom](https://github.com/capricorn86/happy-dom) and TypeScript:

> JSDOM isn't great for performance.

```js
import { Window } from "happy-dom";
import { DOMSerializer, Node } from "prosemirror-model";
import { schema } from "prosemirror-schema-basic";

const window = new Window({ url: "https://localhost:8080" });
const document = window.document;

document.body.innerHTML = '<div id="content"></div>';
const contentDiv = document.getElementById("content");

export const convertJSONtoHTML = (content: Record<string, unknown>) => {
  const contentNode = Node.fromJSON(schema, content);

  DOMSerializer.fromSchema(schema).serializeFragment(
    contentNode.content,
    //@ts-ignore
    { document },
    contentDiv,
  );

  return contentDiv.innerHTML;
};
```

#### Usage:

```js
const content = {
  type: "doc",
  content: [
    {
      type: "heading",
      attrs: {
        id: "milkdown-vanilla-commonmark",
        level: 1,
      },
      content: [
        {
          type: "text",
          text: "Milkdown Vanilla Commonmark",
        },
      ],
    },
    {
      type: "paragraph",
      content: [
        {
          type: "text",
          text: "This is a demo for using Milkdown with ",
        },
      ],
    },
  ],
};

const html = convertJSONtoHTML(content);
console.log(html);
```

Output:

```html
<h1>Milkdown Vanilla Commonmark</h1><p>This is a demo for using Milkdown with </p>
```